# Optimal approach for queue reversal

Tags: queue, reverse

Which method of reversing a queue is better? Recursive calls using function call stack or by directly using an empty stack?

Comment: Depending on your data structure you could also do it in place. The function stack is effectively using a temporary stack too, and probably with a bit more overhead, and there's a chance you'll exceed the allowed stack size too. So allocating a temporary stack or reversing in place feels better to me. But 'optimal' depends more on your specific requirements, and the size of your queues, etc. so I don't think we can give you a general answer.

Comment: If you know you need it reversed, start with a double linked list and forget about reversing by copying stuff around...